# Flutter App to Web through Github pages blank screen

Tags: html, github-pages, flutter-web

I have a page generated by Flutter-Web shops and it is a blank page. And I have an error in the console. This happened after uploading the build web of Flutter into GitHub Pages.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://adamtechnologynl.github.io/') with script ('https://adamtechnologynl.github.io
/flutter_service_worker.js?v=2470069411'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
(index):88 Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.
(anonymous) @ (index):88
(index):47 GET https://adamtechnologynl.github.io/main.dart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
loadMainDartJs @ (index):47
(anonymous) @ (index):91
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. This happens when you have put it another directory instead of the root of the GitHub.

So my code is in "https://username.github.io/demo/book-king/belasting-web-v1/" so that last part we should append everything after "https://username.github.io/" also in the index.html. You can solve it by modifying the line (number 17 by me):

Change:

```
<base href="/">
```

into:

```
<base href="/demo/book-king/belasting-web-v1/">
```

And then you are done.

Answer (score 2):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69884525/2868455) works. But for me, line no 17 was not `<base href="/">`.

It was like this `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">`. Given that **FLUTTER_BASE_HREF** is a variable, it can be modified.

**How?:** Provide `--base-href` argument to `flutter build` like below

HostingURL : https://<github_user_name>.github.io/project_aj/demo/gh-pages/

Apart from the `https://<github_user_name>.github.io` should go as the value for `--base-href`

```
flutter build web --base-href=/project_aj/demo/gh-pages/
```

Comment: To me this is the best solution because you can generate the path when building instead of hard coding it.

Answer (score -1):

After completing your Flutter project, follow these steps to deploy it on GitHub Pages:

**1. Check for the Web Folder:** Ensure that your project contains a web folder. If it's not there, create one using the command:

`flutter create .`

This command initializes a Flutter web project in the current directory, creating the necessary files and folders.

**2. Update the Base URL:** Inside the web folder, locate the `index.html` file. In this file, locate the  tag within the  section. Replace the href attribute with the URL of your GitHub repository. This is the URL where your Flutter project will be hosted.

```
    <base href="https://username.github.io/" />
```

**3. Build the Project:** Run the following command to build the Flutter web project:

`flutter build web`

This command generates the necessary files for the web deployment.

**4. Upload to GitHub:** Upload the generated build files to your GitHub repository. You can do this by committing and pushing the contents of the build/web folder to your repository.

Comment: "_Update the Base URL_" why is this necessary? Please explain.

Comment: If you don't update the base URL in the index.html file, the relative URLs will be incorrect, and the browser won't be able to locate the necessary resources. This can result in broken links, missing styles, and other display issues when accessing your deployed Flutter web application.

By updating the <base> tag to point to the URL of your GitHub Pages deployment, you're effectively telling the browser to use that URL as the base for resolving relative URLs.

Comment: really now? are you sure about that? have you confirmed that what you've just said is true?

Comment: yes, if you don't update the base URL - you will get a blank screen. I tried that !

Comment: really? because I've tried without specifying the base URL and it works just fine.

Comment: did you try hosting on github pages?

Comment: yes. what else? that's what this whole Q&A page is about.

Comment: by default you will get <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF"> .....either you can remove that or u can specify the URL....